# Java - Monitor progress of a async file downloading in server

Tags: java, file, rest, download, progress

I have a server-side application which download file from an external URL into the server. This happens on an async process. I will need to have a Ajax call to get the file download progress and report in UI.

This can be achieved by updating the file download progress into a DB in a defined interval and AJAX call can get progress from Database. But this will be DB resource intensive.

Another option (I'm not sure if this works) is to read the file downloading in progress to compare the size with the total Content-Length to get the % downloaded.

Is there any way to access the OutputStream from the async background process and return the upload % ?

The front end of the application is using AngularJS and backend is implemented using Spring Framework.

File Download code is generic:

```
// opens input stream from the HTTP connection
InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
String saveFilePath = saveDir + File.separator + fileName;

// opens an output stream to save into file
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveFilePath);

int bytesRead = -1;
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
outputStream.close();
inputStream.close();
```

Comment: can you please post your code which downloads the file from url

Comment: @SahilManchanda Added edit for file download code.